# SiteCore Link Check Validation

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Is it possible to set up validation to check all (external) links are valid prior to approving a page?  Is it possible to check links on both link fields and Rich Text editor fields?

I cant find anything in SiteCore's own forum which deals with this.  John West has quite a detailed [blog post](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/Link-Management-with-Sitecore.aspx) on Link Management but it doesnt touch on external links so far as I can see.  He also refers to a [shared source module](http://trac.sitecore.net/LinkProvider/) called LinkProvider but again it doesnt seem to deal with external URLs.

There also seems to a [shared source module](http://trac.sitecore.net/ExternalLinkChecker/) (albeit quite dated) which is meant to do just that but by the looks of things this just reports on broken links as opposed to allowing you to hook something into validation for each page.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the code of the Shared Source tool you mentioned and try to implement the functionality to check external links in your own custom C# class validator.

**Section 4.6.2** of the [Client Configuration Cookbook SC 6.2 (**PDF link**)](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc62keywords/client_configuration_cookbook_sc62_usletter.pdf) has a stub of a custom validator that will get you started.